# Javascript variable in quotes

Tags: php, javascript, html

hai

I want to give a javascript variable within a double Quotes , Can any one help me?

Comment: can you elaborate? perhaps provide a code sample of what you *think* it would be and we can correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using \ in front of the double quotes to escape the character?

```
var myVar="this is my text in \"double quotes\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
var myString = <?=json_encode('This is a "test".');?>;
```

Comment: I don't see that PHP is a tag on the question

Comment: Before anyone jumps on me - check the edit history - it was originally tagged PHP

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're talking about string concatenation. If so, it's like:

```
a = "word";
b = "there should be another " + a + " in the middle of this string.";
```